# JavaScript - Interactive diagrams in Backbone.js application

Tags: backbone.js, raphael, vector-graphics, jsplumb, sankey-diagram

**Background:** I'm currently developing the client side for a web application, using JavaScript, with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) (these are required by the proponent).
This is an application to visualize and edit data, in a graphical mode (through interactive diagrams representing the data, mainly).

**Terminology:** Said data is under the format of multiple *documents*, each containing a *list of items*.
For the purpose of this question, let the items be composed by an *identifier*, a *textual description*, and *links* to items in other documents. Links should be symmetric (`i1 -> i2` exists if and only if `i2 -> i1` also exists).

**The Current Goal:** In this phase, the application should be able to read two documents, display both lists side by side, and then draw lines, connecting the items between both documents, according to their *links*.
These lines should be editable. In other words, the user should be able to create new *links*, or remove existing ones (reflecting the changes on the item models).

These documents can be somewhat long, say, some dozens of items (maybe a few hundreds, in a realistic scenario). Of course, the page will be scrollable, to allow the user to see everything.

Also, for user convenience, there should be a slider to scale the view (allowing *zoom in/out* effects, so the user is given a *global* and a *local* view, being the latter more adequate for editing and the former for analysis).
Furthermore, the user should be allowed to hide particular items (useful when an item has many links, creating *visual rubbish*).

**What I've managed to do:**

- Read data and map it to Backbone models and collections;
- Display both documents side by side (Backbone views), with item connections;
- Allow interactivity on these connections (drag-and-drop to create lines, click to remove), reflecting changes on Backbone models;
- Hide particular items;
- Scale effects.

I've achieved this using [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), after coming across [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html).

**The Problem at Hands:** The application still needs adjustments (emphasis on the scaling effects). Regardless, I found jsPlumb to be comfortable to work with. However, rendering performance seems to be a little lacking, when using the slider (it's possible that the slider steps are too small, thus firing too many events).

The proponent suggested that I try, instead, Sankey diagrams, to represent this kind of data. They also suggested that I try [Sankey by tamc](http://tamc.github.com/Sankey/), based on [Raphaël.js](http://raphaeljs.com/).
Of course, the visual factor is also contributive.

**My question(s):** Does this library have a good compatibility with Backbone? Possibly, if I use the resulting SVG elements as Backbone views' elements.
Also, does any of the two have a significant rendering performance advantage over the other?

On a final note, are there any other libraries more adequate to this scenario, worth the time of rewritting the application, that I might suggest to the proponents?

Comment: Possibly related: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545254/sankey-diagram-in-javascript)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594009/can-i-connect-objects-with-javascript) might also be related.

Comment: Take a look at [diagramo](http://diagramo.com) . HTML5 and GPL.

Comment: Were you successful in including (require-ing) jsPlumb in your application? If so: How did you do it?

Comment: @Benni Even though I ended up using another library, at the time I had a successful prototype running with jsPlumb. If your question is directed at *requireJS* or any other system of its kind, there was none, besides the `<script>` tag in the HTML page, so everything worked with no issues.

Comment: @Benni Let me know if I didn't answer your question. I still have access to the prototype I had then.

Comment: @afsantos Thank you for your answer, it helped me insofar as I am looking for a way to include jsPlumb in a node.js project (using require) Perhaps I just switch to Sankey as you did... Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project is going on, and I ended up using [Sankey by tamc](http://tamc.github.com/Sankey/), with some extra work of my own, to better adapt it to this particular case.

[image]